# How to load many CSV files in a folder using Python?

Tags: python, pickle

I am new to python code and started to notice this `pickle` function in python. I am trying to load all (50) `csv` files in a folder and save it as `pickle` files. The `csv` files might contain same or different column names too. Any suggestions on how to approach that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please always provide a [mcve] and be sure to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need to attempt it yourself, and then ask questions about specific problems you are having. At the moment you are saying "I don't know where to start". If this is really true, you need to read a tutorial.

Comment: where are the files currently? If as I understand you want to move all csv files into one directory, then look into `os.walk`, `os.mkdir`, and `shutil`.

Comment: @Pitto  "Not all questions benefit from including code." [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) People seem to forget to read SO's help center. We are here to help, no?

Comment: While this is true @Raphael don't forget that SO is not a place where people do your homeworks or do your job in your place.
Writing code may not be mandatory but it will lead you easily to the downvote / question close path (like you see it is already happening for this question). Please read this, for example: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ and also read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @Pitto I understand the reasons, I even agree but it goes against the spirit of SO. If people deny help based on what you say then they should participate in another community perhaps.

Comment: I am not an coding god or a SO king but I have enough years on the platform and points to feel confident enough to share a reasonable point of view.
Explore the website and find a confirmation or denial of what I say for yourself.

Comment: _I am trying to load all (50) csv files in a folder and save it as pickle files._ Why? What have you tried? Have you done any research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
import glob, os
import pandas as pd
import pickle

os.chdir(r"path/to/folder")
df_list = []
for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df_list.append(df)

with open(r'\df_list.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(df_list, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```